# Distance too close

Tags: c#, performance, .net, computational-geometry

Are two points too close?
Trying to do the math as efficiently as possible.

deltaX + deltaY is going to be > than the actual distance

You might use this in game play - are players in range?

```
// test
bool distanceTooClose = DistanceTooClose(new System.Windows.Point(12, 12), new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), 17);
// end test

static bool DistanceTooClose(System.Windows.Point x, System.Windows.Point y, Double minDistance)
{
    double deltaX = Math.Abs(y.X - x.X);
    double deltaY = Math.Abs(y.Y - x.Y);
    if((deltaX + deltaY) < minDistance)
    {
        return false;
    }
    double distanceSquared = deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY;
    //double distance = Math.Sqrt(distanceSquared);
    Double minDistanceSquared = minDistance * minDistance;
    return (distanceSquared <= minDistanceSquared);
}
```

Comment: What prompted you to write this? How's it used? You went quite minimalistic on the explanation this time ;-)

Comment: @Mast Just playing around.  For a game are player in range.

Comment: Don’t you have a `hypot` function as in C? That is an intrinsic and can use the best special CPU instructions that are made for that.

Comment: @JDługosz There is the option of `Point.Subtract(p1, p2).Length)` (and `.LengthSquared`. Whether or not it would have the best CPU usage or not, I don't know.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypot @BrianJ yes, using Point arithmetic rather than doing x and y separately is better. Especially since it already has a Point value!

Comment: @JDługosz I didn't realize that `hypot` was a specific (and different) algorithm that a standard hypotenuse approach. Thanks for the link!

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0030r1.pdf) interesting — it’s a rationale for making a 3D version, and it mentions how useful and prevelent it is etc. «…may  allow  library implementers  to  take  advantage  of  any  underlying  hardware  that  provides  optimized  instructions»  @BrianJ

Comment: As for different algorithm, doing things “carefully” is a whole field of study in numerical methods, and it can be eye-opening to read [details of how the various library functions are implemented](https://www.amazon.com/Standard-C-Library-P-J-Plauger/dp/0131315099).

Comment: I tested System.Windows.Point.Subtract(pointA, pointB).Length; and it as slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that you should run a benchmark on to see whether the branch is worth avoiding the 3 multiplications.

It is very likely that the branch will not be worth it due to how branch prediction works. But that depends on what data you will be feeding into it and in how tight of a loop you call it.

Comment: exactly... without a proof there is no optimization ;-)

Comment: You are correct it does not appear to speed it up.  Shocked me.

Comment: Also you can just ask the caller to pass `minDistanceSquared` instead of `minDistance`, since they may have that handy anyway or be able to compute it at compile time.

Answer (score 11):

#### Use types consistently

I prefer `double` over `Double`, but it doesn't really matter which you use as long as it's consistent. Mixing them, though, means unnecessary cognitive load.

#### Naming

> ```
>     ...(y.X - x.X);
>     ...(y.Y - x.Y);
> ```

In my opinion, `x` and `y` are about the worst possible names for a type which has members called `X` and `Y`. If you insist on one-character names for points, mathematical conventions would typically name them `A`, `B`, ... or `P`, `Q`, ...

Also the method itself: `DistanceTooClose`. Whether the distance is too close or close enough is a question of the calling context. The method really checks `IsDistanceCloserThan`.

#### Argument validation

What should the following test give?

```
DistanceTooClose(new System.Windows.Point(1, 1), new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), -2);
```

#### KISS

The simplest implementation of the core test is

```
    var deltaX = q.X - p.X;
    var deltaY = q.Y - p.Y;
    return deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY <= minDistance * minDistance;
```

Anything more complicated than that should have a comment explaining why the complication has been added.

Comment: <=  is not CloserThan.  I like the variables for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The `if((deltaX + deltaY) < minDistance)` did not speed it up
Math.Abs is not required as squaring

```
static bool DistanceTooClose(System.Windows.Point pointA, System.Windows.Point pointB, Double minDistance)
{
    double deltaX = pointA.X - pointB.X;
    double deltaY = pointA.Y - pointB.Y;
    double distanceSquared = deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY;
    //double distance = Math.Sqrt(distanceSquared);
    //return (distance <= minDistance);
    double minDistanceSquared = minDistance * minDistance;
    return (distanceSquared <= minDistanceSquared);
}
```